# MongoDB aggregation - grouping data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB collection containing user activity data (activity type) and I would like to group activities into two groups and return count of activities.

Collection looks something like this (there are also some other fields like date etc.):

```
{"userID": 1, "activity": "reading"}
{"userID": 1, "activity": "sleeping"}
{"userID": 1, "activity": "hiking"}
{"userID": 1, "activity": "sleeping"}
{"userID": 1, "activity": "biking"}
```

I wanna do aggregation that will return count of multiple activities grouped, eg. I would like to group "hiking" and "biking" as "recreation" and "sleeping" and "reading" as "resting" and than count of activities since selected date for specified user:

```
"recreation": 2
"resting": 3
```

What I did was to match `userID` and `date` `$gte` to get all activities for selected user and period, tried counting, `$sum`, `$project`, but couldn't get it to work as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$group` with `$cond`

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userID",
      recreation: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $or: [
                {$eq: ["$activity","hiking"]},
                {$eq: ["$activity","biking"]}
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      resting: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $or: [
                {$eq: ["$activity","sleeping"]},
                {$eq: ["$activity","reading"]}
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HlXFUbVwjOq)**